# Change WinForm control by dropdown options

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

[Control screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDehF.png)

i am trying to change the red highlighted control by the above combo box control which has following options:

[Options dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKq21.png)

can anyone guide me please.

Comment: You need to show the code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: i dont have code because i was not getting where to start from

Answer (score 0):

Add a panel above your comboBox for your ease.

[image: See this Image]

and double click on your comboBox it will generate **comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged**
write this code

```
    private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPanel.Controls.Clear();
        string selectedText = comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower();
        if (selectedText == "combobox")
        {
            MyPanel.Controls.Add(new ComboBox());
        }
        else if (selectedText == "textbox")
        {
            MyPanel.Controls.Add(new TextBox());

        }
        else if (selectedText == "radio")
        {
            MyPanel.Controls.Add(new RadioButton());

        }
        else if (selectedText == "checkbox")
        {
            MyPanel.Controls.Add(new CheckBox());

        }
        MyPanel.Refresh();
    }
```